# How to declare a static integer in h class in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, static

I am not able to declare a static integer in h class in iPhone.

```
 static int i;
```

This gives an error:

> expected specifier-qualifier list before static

How to resolve this? How can I declare a static variable globally in iPhone?

Comment: That should work (though I don't recommend putting object definitions in header files).  Can you show us some more context?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a global static variable. A static variable has file scope — and for .h files, that means every file it's included in gets a different variable called `i`. To declare a global variable, put the declaration `extern int i` in your header and just `int i` in the global scope in one implementation file (it doesn't technically matter which one).